# Code not passing final test case on LeetCode #451, working for all other test cases?

Tags: java

I am hoping someone can help me understand why my code isn't working for a certain test case. This is about question 451: Sort Characters by Frequency on LeetCode. Here is the goal: "Given a string, sort it in decreasing order based on the frequency of characters." My code passed 34/35 of the test cases, but not the last one. I am wondering why my code worked for the other test cases but not this last one, and what I can do to fix it so it works for the last test case as well?

```
 class Solution {
public String frequencySort(String s) {
    Map<Character, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(char c: s.toCharArray()){
        map.put(c, map.getOrDefault(c, 0) + 1);
    }
    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(s.length());
    Map<Character,Integer> sorted = new TreeMap<>(new Comparator<Character>() {
        @Override
        public int compare(Character a, Character b){
            Integer aValue = map.get(a);
            Integer bValue = map.get(b);
            if(aValue == bValue) return 1;
            return bValue.compareTo(aValue);
        }
    });
    sorted.putAll(map);
    for(Map.Entry<Character,Integer> entry: sorted.entrySet()){
        int length = entry.getValue();
        char toAdd = entry.getKey();
        for(int i = 1; i <= length; i++){
            sb.append(toAdd);
        }
    }
    return new String(sb);
}
}
```

[Test Case](https://leetcode.com/submissions/detail/199988684/testcase/)

Comment: What is the 35th character sample in the test? Can you debug your code with that test sample?

Comment: I attached the test case as a link since it was too big to copy and paste. I cannot feasibly debug with that sample because it is 28,000 characters long, and I am unable to see where I went wrong on Leetcode because the test is too long for it to highlight my error.

Comment: Hard to verify without a LeetCode acoount

Comment: try:  if(aValue == bValue) return 0;

Comment: oops, try  if(aValue.equals(bValue)) return 0

Comment: Thank you Ray! I did if(aValue.equals(bValue)) return 1 so that the Map didn't delete duplicates and it worked. Your answer worked perfectly!

Comment: Hi, and welcome to stackoverflow.com! As a general rule, questions should not rely on external links to make sense. Your question however relies on a link to leetcode, which furthermore requires an account. Could you add the failing test to your question, and possibly create a testcase that is freely accessible? Otherwise the question will likely be closed.

Comment: Note: You can use for example https://ideone.com/ to create a self-contained testcase that anyone can run in the browser (or download).

Answer (score -1):

Simple Scala Solution here if you want:

```
object Solution {
  def frequencySort(s: String): String = {
    import collection.mutable.Map
    val count: Map[Char, Int] = Map().withDefaultValue(0)
    for {
      c <- s
    } {
      count(c) += 1
    }
    count
      .toList.map(x => (x._2, x._1))
      .sorted
      .reverse
      .flatMap(x => List.fill(x._1)(x._2.toString))
      .foldLeft("")(_ + _)
  }
}
```